# Four transformations for the figure $8$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

[image] I have found two transformation matrices: rotation by $90$ degrees and rotation by $270$ degrees.

What will be the other two? Mostly I am missing the combined transformation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The other two transformations are reflections. If you prefer, you could decompose these transformations into reflections across the $x$ or $y$ axis followed by a rotation.

Comment: Then it will be reflection then rotation and then again reflection?

Comment: @User56 No, you should only be applying a reflection once. Applying two reflections means that you would end up with one of the two transformations that you already listed

Comment: @User56 Or perhaps you meant that *one* of the transformations is a rotation then reflection and *the other* is just a reflection. If so, then that's technically correct; both of the missing transformations can be characterized either as a reflection or as a reflection followed by a rotation.

Comment: but that i tried... if i reflect the image over x axis then by rotation i am not able to bring the final image.

Comment: @User56 What about a reflection over the $x$-axis followed by a $90$-degree rotation?

Comment: Divide the original $8$ into four parts by cutting along its two lines of symmetry (one vertical, one horizontal). Color each of those four parts a different color. Now, after your two transformations, think about how these colors are positioned when the $8$ is at the new location. How many ways can the second $8$ be colored so that the colors have the same relationship to each other (sharing a lobe, adjacent on opposite lobes, diagonally opposite) as in the original figure? Your two transformations can only produce two of those combinations. How can you get the others?

Comment: And FYI - the $x$ and $y$ axes are not the only lines you can reflect through. You can do it with any line at all.